# How to write Nested Loop in Kernel side OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I'm a beginner in `OpenCL`. I'm trying to implement an `OpenCL` application.I have a doubt that how to write `opencl` **kernel code** . i have given a  original `c` code.

> **Question** :- help me to change that given c code into `opencl` **kernel code**?.

ORIGINAL C CODE:

```
int i, j;

// initialization of indexes
for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    Index[i] = i;

// Bubble sort
for (i = 0; i<n - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (I[i] > I[j])
        {
            double z = I[i];    // exchange attractiveness
            I[i] = I[j];
            I[j] = z;
            z = f[i];           // exchange fitness
            f[i] = f[j];
            f[j] = z;
            int k = Index[i];   // exchange indexes
            Index[i] = Index[j];
            Index[j] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It becomes odd-even sort after parallelization with only the "if" part altered.

Comment: Please also paste your `OpenCL` code draft and optionally tells what's wrong with it, or which parts you are in trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Example for 4096 element arrays(alternate bubble1 and bubble2 at least 2048 times--->4096(N) kernel executions ):

index init on host side since its just assignment.
Auxiliary functions:

```
void swap2p(__private int * I,int i,int j)
{
        int tmp=I[i];
        I[i]=I[j];
        I[j]=tmp;
}
void swap2g(__global int * I,int i,int j)
{
        int tmp=I[i];
        I[i]=I[j];
        I[j]=tmp;
}
```

Alternating kernel-1:

```
__kernel void bubble1(__global int * I, __global int * f, __global int * Index){
       int threadId=get_global_id(0);
       __private int vals[2];

       if(threadId*2+1<4096)
       { 
              vals[0]=I[threadId*2];
              vals[1]=I[threadId*2+1];
              if(vals[0]>vals[1])
              {      
                    swap2p(vals,threadId*2,threadId*2+1);
                    swap2g(f,threadId*2,threadId*2+1);
                    swap2g(Index,threadId*2,threadId*2+1);
                    I[threadId*2]=vals[0];
                    I[threadId*2+1]=vals[1];
              }
       }
}
```

alternating kernel-2:

```
__kernel void bubble2(__global int * I){
       int threadId=get_global_id(0);
       __private int vals[2];

       if(threadId*2+2<4096)
       {
              vals[0]=I[threadId*2+1];
              vals[1]=I[threadId*2+2];
              if(vals[0]>vals[1])
              {      
                    swap2p(vals,threadId*2+1,threadId*2+2);
                    swap2g(f,threadId*2+1,threadId*2+2);
                    swap2g(Index,threadId*2+1,threadId*2+2);
                    I[threadId*2+1]=vals[0];
                    I[threadId*2+2]=vals[1];
              }
       }
}
```

Global thread number: N/2 (2048)

Comment: Is it optimal to perform 3 XOR on global memory? Isn't it better to just store it in a temporal variable?

Comment: Well, bubble sort is quite bad anyway :P. I think your solution is ok, but the swap thing got me thinking what would be better a swap or a XOR....

Comment: You are right, it has %50 more acceses to vram. Now it is 4 accesses using tmp. Even "if" part needs same variables.

Comment: Updated "if" blocks. Now even with comparison, total of 4 globals for "I" array.

Comment: After years of fighting with CL compilers, I learnt that they normally don't optimize global reads/writes at all, since they suppose that the second access may return a different value (due to another thread updating the content). So if you read the same variable from global 3 times, the compiler will do 3 global reads. It improves a lot the performance when those reads are cached/avoided by the programmer. Even if they look obvious at first glance...

Comment: Yes, and opencl needs non atomic xchg(between two memory points) or some two way stream instruction too.